# django table information displayed twice

Tags: django

django table information displayed twice

Why is the Due date and time remaining appear twice? I am trying figure out what is that coming from. I am still learning django, slowly. Sometimes, I'm just having trouble.

Picture:
http://gyazo.com/cae11df54df3f558865a772529f97139.png

.html code

```
            {% if toolsBorrowed %}
            <table id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Tool Name</th>
                        <th>Owner</th>
                        <th>Due Date</th>
                        <th>Time Remaining</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="myTable">
                    {% for tool in toolsBorrowed %}
                        {% query Request borrowerId=user.id as req %}   
                        {% query userAcc pk=tool.owner as owner %} 
                        <tr style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="document.location = '/view_tool/{{ tool.id }}/';">
                            <td>{{ tool.name }}</td>
                            <td>{% for o in owner %}{{ o.username }}{% endfor %}</td>
                            {% for r in req %}

                                <td>{{ r.dueDate }}</td>
                            <td>{{ r.dueDate | timeuntil }}</td>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            {% else %}
                <strong>You are not borrowing any tools.</strong>
            {% endif %}
```

views.py

```
def borrowed(request):
    context = {'toolsBorrowed': Tool.objects.filter(borrower = request.user.id),
                'toolsLoan':Tool.objects.filter(owner = request.user.id).exclude(borrower = None),
               'userAcc' : userAcc.objects,
               'Request' : Request.objects,
               }    
    return render(request, 'borrowed.html', context)
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: you can print out all your `Tool` object first to see if it's not the display to blame.

Comment: `r.duedate` and `r.duedate|timeuntil` is creating twice.

Comment: Well, you're iterating through `req`, so presumably that contains two elements. But since you haven't shown the code of the `query` custom tag, there's no way to tell you why it might be returning two objects.